# How to group notification on php and mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli, notifications

How can i group notification on php and mysqli

I have this table for notifications

```
id
usersent : user who sent the notification
userreseved : user who reseved the notification
message_id
notitype : 1 for answer notifications and 2 for likes notifications
notiseen
timesent
```

and i have this function to show notifications on notifications class

```
public function show_notifications($username){
        global $mysqli;

        $safeusername = trim(htmlentities($username, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"));
        $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli->link, $safeusername);


        $show_notifications = "SELECT * FROM notifications where userreseved='$myusername' order by timesent desc"; 
        $get_notifications = $mysqli->select($show_notifications);

        if($get_notifications){
        return $get_notifications;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }

    }
```

and this is my notifications page

```
<?php


$show_notifications = $notifications->show_notifications($username_user_me);

while ($rows_notifications = mysqli_fetch_array($show_notifications)) {

$id_notifications            = $rows_notifications['id'];
$usersent_notifications      = $rows_notifications['usersent'];
$userreseved_notifications   = $rows_notifications['userreseved'];
$message_id_notifications    = $rows_notifications['message_id'];
$notitype_notifications      = $rows_notifications['notitype'];
$notiseen_notifications      = $rows_notifications['notiseen'];
$timesent_notifications      = $rows_notifications['timesent'];

if($notitype_notifications == 1){
    echo "<div class='alert alert-info'> {$usersent_notifications} answer your message</div>";
}
else if($notitype_notifications == 2){
    echo "<div class='alert alert-info'>{$usersent_notifications} like your answer{$message_id_notifications}</div>";
}
?>


<?php
}
?>
```

this work fine, but it gives data like this

- Peter like your answer (message_id : 5)
- Jacky like your answer  (message_id : 5)

i want to group related notification in one notification like this

- Peter and 5 others like your answer (message_id : 5)
- Medo and 2 others like your answer (message_id : 7)

any ideas?

Comment: group by `message_id` in query. get the `count(id)`. another query to get the first `usersent`(or who should be 'Peter'?) to show later.

Answer (score 0):

We can try joining to a subquery which aggregates `notifications` by message, and determines both the earliest message in the thread and the number of replies at the same time.

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(n1.usersent, ' and ', CAST(n2.cnt - 1 AS CHAR(10)),
           ' others like your answer (message_id: ', n1.message_id, ')') AS msg,
    n1.id,
    n1.usersent
    -- and maybe other columns you want
FROM notifications n1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT message_id, MIN(timesent) AS min_timesent, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM notifications
    GROUP BY message_id
) n2
    ON n1.message_id = n2.message_id AND
       n1.timesent = n2.min_timesent
WHERE
    n1.userreseved = '$myusername';
```

Comment: @MahmoudSamy You can just do `SELECT n1.*` to include every column from the `notifications` table.